# Autowiring into JPA converters

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I am using a customized ObjectMapper in my spring boot app. I also use the JPA converters for several fields which are stored as JSON strings in the DB. I am not sure how to autowire my custom object mapper into my converter.

```
@Convert(converter=AddressConverter.class)
private Address address;
```

And my AddressConverter is

```
class AddressConverter implements AttributeConverter<Address, String> {

        @Autowire
        ObjectMapper objectMapper; //How to do this?
        .....
        .....
   }
```

How to autowire `ObjectMapper` into `AddressConverter`? Is there a way to do this with Spring AOP?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219421/accessing-spring-beans-inside-attributeconverter-class which has more details.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe you can do it by changing it to a **static** property, like this:

```
@Component
class AddressConverter implements AttributeConverter<Address, String> {

    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper; 

    @Autowired
    public void setObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper){
        AddressConverter.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }
    .....
    .....
}
```

Comment: This did work for me. Although I also had to add the annotation `@Converter` and make sure the Converter is autowired somewhere else so that spring actually initialized it.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. Tried n0daft's suggestions as well, but the field is always null.

Comment: I am also having troubles with Spring Data JPA project, I found there should be some kind of override converters.add method, but still in issue state... :-(

Comment: It worked for me too, but I'm not able to understand how, can you please explain.

Comment: Why does field needs to be static? Please explain

Comment: I believe this is related to how Hibernate handles AttributeConverters' lifecycle. Having a static attribute for the mapper makes all instances of AddressConverter -in this example- share the same autowired mapper.

Comment: really good way

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your converter with @Component then Spring will create an instance of it by calling the constructor of your converter.

The constructor will autowire dependencies which you can then save it as a static field variable.

When JPA creates this this instance, it won't pass the dependencies like Spring did but because the static field of JPA's instance was already set when Spring created another instance, the dependencies does work