# Accessing Spring Beans inside AttributeConverter class

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm developing a Spring Data JPA application, and I've created an `AttributeConverter` class in order to save an `ArrayList` of objects as JSON in a database column. Inside this class I need to make use of a class I have defined as a Spring Bean.

As the `AttributeConverter` class is managed by Hibernate, it seems to be instantiated before any Spring beans are created, and therefore DI does not seem to work (the Spring Bean in the `AttributeConverter` class is `null`, and I'm getting a `NullPointer` exception thrown). So at the moment I'm creating another instance of the said bean to be able to use it in the `AttributeConverter` class (which defeats the purpose of DI).

I've also tried creating a Util class (annotated with `@Component`) which implements `ApplicationContextAware`, which provides a method giving the SpringBean (`cxt.getBean(BeanClass.class)`). But this also is instantiated **after** the `AttributeConverter`.

Is there any idea of how this can be solved?

Thank you.

Comment: duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3813725/3285997

Comment: @tom01 No it is not. The link you provided is about objects that one controls when they are created, in case of AttributeConverter it is not possible.

Comment: The link shows how to autowire an instance that was not initialized by the Spring container, what is different in this scenario? Surely just get  reference to the AttributeConverter instance created by Hibernate and autowire using AutowireCapableBeanFactory at the appropriate app lifecycle point.

Answer (score 27):

With JPA 2.2, Spring 5.1(
[SPR-16305](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20852)) and Hibernate 5.3.0 ([HHH-12135](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12135)) you no longer need to use the mutable static property hack and can use dependency injection just like you would on a regular spring managed bean (note that annotations are no longer necessary):

```
public class MyAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<X,Y> {

    private final MySpringBean bean;

    public MyAttributeConverter(MySpringBean bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
    }

    public Y convertToDatabaseColumn(X attribute) {
      ...
    }

    public X convertToEntityAttribute(Y dbData) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Here's what I had to do: Upgrade to Spring Boot 2.1 (since that uses Spring 5.1), together with spring cloud version Greenwich.RELEASE (if you want to omit the parent pom). Add spring.jpa.database-platform to my application.properties, add the timezone to the DB connection URL, and remove the annotations from the AttibuteConverter (not sure if that is strictly needed).

Comment: It works with Spring Boot 2.1 unless i add `@Converter` annotation to the`MyAttributeConverter` class

Comment: You have to annotate the field with `@Converter`. I mean, it doesn't work with `@Converter(autoApply = false)` (at least not in my tests, it didn't...)

Comment: Didn't work for me, I updated to spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.5. My converter looks exactly the same. But application fails to start with error message `NoSuchMethodException` - complains that there is no default constructor

Comment: I just get `org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate managed bean directly : com.my.AttributeConverter Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.my.AttributeConverter.<init>()`. Is there a link to where this feature is documented properly and in detail? Seems that there's more to it than this answer gives away. Thanks!

Comment: OK, so if you've customized your JPA configuration (i.e. defining your own `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`), this will NOT work out of the box, you need to configure the JPA property that connects the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` to Spring's `BeanFactory` yourself as per [Jürgen Höller's comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20852#issuecomment-453465206).

Comment: Closest thing to documentation about this that I can find, then, is https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html#BEAN_CONTAINER and https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringBeanContainer.html .

Answer (score 23):

You can inject a bean(@Component, @Service, @Repository) inside an AttributeConverter using static properties

Setps:

1. Set in your AttributeConverter with the following annotations: @Component, @Converter and @Configurable
2. Define the field that you want to be autowired with the static modifier access
3. Create an init method in order to autowire the repository
4. Implement the methods defined in the interface AttributeConverter

Basically, the code should look like this...

```
// Step 1
@Component
@Converter
@Configurable
public class MyAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<X,Y> {
    // Where: X = the type of the entity attribute and Y = the type of the database column
    
    // Step 2
    private static MyRepository myRepository;
    
    //Step 3
    @Autowired
    public void initMyRepository(MyRepository myRepository){
        MyAttributeConverter.myRepository = myRepository;
    }
    
    // Step 4
    Y convertToDatabaseColumn(X attribute){//TODO implement method}
    X convertToEntityAttribute(Y dbData){//TODO implement method}
}
```

I hope it can help!!!

Comment: It works, but I still look for a clean way to do this (without the static field).

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 7):

Generally Ipandzic's answer is the right hint I guess. However it did not work for me how he described it. I argument-constructor also looks a little strange in a Spring-environment. I played around a bit and was able to use an AttributeConverter of the following form (indeed you do not need the `@Converter`-annotation or any other on the `AttributeConverter`-class itself):

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class MyConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {
    @Autowired
    private MyBean mybean;

    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String value) {
        return myBean.changeValue(value);
    }

    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbValue) {
        return myBean.undoChange(dbValue);
    }
}
```

But creating this class and upgrading to Spring-Boot 2.1 (including Spring 5.1, Hibernate 5.3 and JPA 2.2) did not do the trick for me. The thing was, that I used `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` to configure my persistent storage which will not enable Dependency injection for `AttributeConverter`s. Reading the first link Ipandzic posted suggests you have to bring `LocalSessionFactoryBuilder` into play somehow. That's why I ended up with the following configuration:

```
//...

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, Environment env) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);

    // somehow tell the factory where you entitiy-definitions are, this is just
    // one possibility of doing so:
    String entityPackage = JpaMarkerModel.class.getPackage().getName();
    log.info("EntityManager will scan for entities in package [{}].", entityPackage);
    factory.setPackagesToScan(entityPackage);

    return factory;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}

//...
```

This "answer" is merely an addition to Ipandzi's, but maybe it helps some people to solve their problem quicker than I did.

Comment: Prefer using `@EnableEntityScan` annotation instead.

Comment: Does that have something to do with the problem at hand? Why should I prefer using that annotation?

Comment: There is a way to continue using a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` by setting a bean factory for Hibernate. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23968#issuecomment-570131791

Comment: I had a similar issue, upgraded all the dependencies but still no autowiring. The mention of `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` was a clue - we were explicitly creating it in our application context/config and so a non-Spring BeanContainer was being used. The link to the Github issue provided the answer for me: `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(); emfb.getJpaPropertyMap().put(AvailableSettings.BEAN_CONTAINER, new SpringBeanContainer(beanFactory));`

Comment: what a solution what should I do explain it clearly